# How are one-of types achieved using subclassing in object-oriented languages?

Tags: oop, types, subclassing, ml

From the [notes](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/proglang/proglang-003/lecture_slides/section2/section2sum.pdf) of a course on programming languages (*page 2, second paragraph*),

> In object-oriented languages with classes like Java, one-of types are
>   achieved with subclassing

What's meant by *one-of* types here is what programming language researchers often refer to as *sum types* (e.g., types like `option` types in ML and enumerations in C and Java).

There was a suggestion by someone that, in an object-oriented language, if `W` is a super-type of `X` and `Y`, then `W` is a one-of type in the sense that a sub-type of `W` is either `X` *or* `Y`. But then I wondered, what if there's a sub-type `Z` of a sub-type of `W`, let's say `X`. In this case, a sub-type of `W` could be an `X` *and* a `Z`.

This is a little bit confusing, but is the idea of having `Z` as a sub-type of `X` as a sub-type of `W` is the same as *nesting* an each-of type (aka product type) inside of a one-of type (i.e., `W`)?

If I'm getting this whole idea in the wrong way, then how are one-of types achieved using subclassing in object-oriented languages?

Comment: Most OOP literature I've seen tends to contemplate "is-a" (inheritance) and "has-a" (composition) relationships. This sounds like someone trying to look at the inheritance relationship from the other direction (an `Animal` is "one of" `Cat`, `Dog`, `Horse`, `Pig`, ... instead of a `Cat` "is a(n)" `Animal`, etc.). There might be some good reasons the literature tends to look at it from the direction it does, as this "one of" notion seems confusing (but maybe that's just because I'm more used to the other way...) and probably harder to reason correctly about... Didn't read the link, though...

Comment: @twalberg this might not be the most perfect example on a benefit of looking at it that way, but as the notes suggest, one of the benefits of one-of types is _using different data in different situations_. For example, if a student is identified using their ID number _or_ their name (if they don't have an ID), then a type whose value is a number or a string would be a good choice. If you take that to an object-oriented language (_and assuming I get it right_), having a class `ID` which has 2 sub-classes `Name` and `Number` can be used to achieve the same task.

Comment: That description makes it sound more like what C or C++ use a `union` for (or Pascal's variant types - I forget exactly what they were called or how they were used; it's been a looonnng time since my Pascal days) - a single type that at any one point in time might represent one concrete type (an integer or floating point number or string), but later on (after some assignment operations), it might have a completely different type...

Comment: @twalberg yeah I know something about that already. I think I understand the idea of a one-of type, I'm just not sure that I exactly understand how this could be achieved using subclassing in an object-oriented language. It's a little bit confusing as you see.